# GLSL: How do I cast a float to an int?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-es

In a GLSL fragment shader I am trying to cast a `float` into an `int`. The compiler raises an error:

```
ERROR: 0:60: '=' :  cannot convert from 'mediump float' to 'highp int'
```

I tried raising the precision of the `int`:

```
mediump float indexf = floor(2.0 * mixer);
highp int index = indexf;
```

but to no avail.

How do I cast the `int` properly?

Comment: For future reference, you will get better answers if you ask general programming questions like this one at Stack Overflow. http://www.stackoverflow.com/ - depending on community feedback this question might be migrated there anyway.

Comment: For reinterpret casts, there are now functions such as [`floatBitsToInt`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/floatBitsToInt.xhtml).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
highp int index = int(indexf);
```

I found it [here](http://www.gpgpu.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4857).

Comment: Also note that casting a float to an int automatically floors it (at least in any implementation I've ever seen) so your call to floor should be unnecessary.

Comment: In most languages the rounding mode is truncate / round-to-zero, which is equivalent to floor for positive numbers but not negative numbers. I don't remember if this applies to GLSL, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't.

Comment: @Joe That's an interesting fact that I never thought about, and I just confirmed it with a Java test case.

Comment: Is highp important here? (On an Integer)

Comment: Thanks, it also worked in my case. Could you update the reference that you have put, since the page doesn't exist?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what that forum post from 7 years ago was, and `archive.org` seems to be missing it. Not gonna update the link. But I'll leave it in case some other web archaeologist is more skilled than me.

Comment: How cna I convert this to const so that I can sample an array?